# Pick One Row per Unique ID from duplicate records

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

In Ms.Access 2010, I have a similar query table like one below where its displaying duplicate records. Problem is that even though I have unique ID's, one of the field has different data than other row since I have combined two seperate tables in this query. I just want to display one row per ID and eliminate other rows. It doesn't matter which row I pick. See below:

```
ID - NAME - FAVCOLOR
1242 - John - Blue
1242 - John - Red  
1378 - Mary - Green
```

I want to just pick any of the the row with same ID. It doesn't matter which row I pick as long as I am displaying one row per ID is what matters.

```
ID - NAME - FAVCOLOR
1242 - John - Red  
1378 - Mary - Green
```

Comment: What is your actual sql query to retrieve rows at the moment ?

Comment: SELECT ID, NAME, FAVCOLOR
FROM TABLE1;

UNION ALL

SELECT ID, NAME, FAVCOLOR
FROM TABLE2;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SQL from your current query as a subquery and then `GROUP BY` `ID` and `NAME`.  You can retrieve the minimum `FAVCOLOR` since you want only one and don't care which.

```
SELECT sub.ID, sub.NAME, Min(sub.FAVCOLOR)
FROM
    (
        SELECT ID, [NAME], FAVCOLOR
        FROM TABLE1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, [NAME], FAVCOLOR
        FROM TABLE2
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.ID, sub.NAME;
```

Note `NAME` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).  Bracket that name or prefix it with the table name or alias to avoid confusing the db engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting union without the ALL parameter and see if you get the desired result.

Your new query would look like

"SELECT ID, NAME, FAVCOLOR FROM TABLE1; UNION SELECT ID, NAME, FAVCOLOR FROM TABLE2;"

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the IDs, why is the color in the query?  Maybe I'm missing something.
The only thing I could suggest is to use some aggregate function (min, max) to get one color.

```
    Select
    id,
    name,
    max(favcolor)
    from (
    (select * from table1) t1
    union (select * from table2) t2 )t
    group by
    id,
    name
```

Comment: Report needs to be sorted by Color thats why need color, anyways I will try this out now and see if it works.